# component class not found hibernate

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I am getting the error "component class not found: Sustainability.ProductionSavingId "whenever I try to connect ireport with hibernate in netbeans. The program does not show any error when I run it but when I try to connect ireport to the datebase using hibernate it throws the error.  I have already added the needed classpath and jar files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 1, 2013 7:21:28 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Sustainability.Productionsaving" table="productionsaving"                          catalog="gdp">
        <composite-id name="id" class="Sustainability.ProductionsavingId">
            <key-property name="categoryName" type="string">
                <column name="CategoryName" length="25" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="date" type="timestamp">
                <column name="Date" length="19" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="users" class="Sustainability.Users" fetch="select">
            <column name="Username" length="20" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="Sustainability.Category" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="CategoryName" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="savingAmount" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="SavingAmount" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="quantity" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="Quantity" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="unit" type="string">
            <column name="Unit" length="5" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 1, 2013 7:21:28 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Sustainability.Productionsaving" table="productionsaving"                          catalog="gdp">
        <composite-id name="id" class="Sustainability.ProductionsavingId">
            <key-property name="categoryName" type="string">
                <column name="CategoryName" length="25" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="date" type="timestamp">
                <column name="Date" length="19" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="users" class="Sustainability.Users" fetch="select">
            <column name="Username" length="20" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="Sustainability.Category" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="CategoryName" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="savingAmount" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="SavingAmount" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="quantity" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="Quantity" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="unit" type="string">
            <column name="Unit" length="5" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>






/**
 * Productionsaving generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Productionsaving  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private ProductionsavingId id;
     private Users users;
     private Category category;
     private Double savingAmount;
     private Double quantity;
     private String unit;

    public Productionsaving() {
    }


    public Productionsaving(ProductionsavingId id, Category category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
    }
    public Productionsaving(ProductionsavingId id, Users users, Category category, Double savingAmount, Double quantity, String unit) {
       this.id = id;
       this.users = users;
       this.category = category;
       this.savingAmount = savingAmount;
       this.quantity = quantity;
       this.unit = unit;
    }

    public ProductionsavingId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ProductionsavingId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Users getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public Double getSavingAmount() {
        return this.savingAmount;
    }

    public void setSavingAmount(Double savingAmount) {
        this.savingAmount = savingAmount;
    }
    public Double getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getUnit() {
        return this.unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}


    import java.util.Date;

/**
 * ProductionsavingId generated by hbm2java
 */
public class ProductionsavingId  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private String categoryName;
     private Date date;

    public ProductionsavingId() {
    }

    public ProductionsavingId(String categoryName, Date date) {
       this.categoryName = categoryName;
       this.date = date;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return this.categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof ProductionsavingId) ) return false;
         ProductionsavingId castOther = ( ProductionsavingId ) other; 

         return ( (this.getCategoryName()==castOther.getCategoryName()) || ( this.getCategoryName()!=null && castOther.getCategoryName()!=null && this.getCategoryName().equals(castOther.getCategoryName()) ) )
 && ( (this.getDate()==castOther.getDate()) || ( this.getDate()!=null && castOther.getDate()!=null && this.getDate().equals(castOther.getDate()) ) );
   }

   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;

         result = 37 * result + ( getCategoryName() == null ? 0 : this.getCategoryName().hashCode() );
         result = 37 * result + ( getDate() == null ? 0 : this.getDate().hashCode() );
         return result;
   }   


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you are referencing the class which does not exist in the classpath. Make sure that you reference the class with the proper package name and class name. Your package name seems not standard to me. It should be something like

`com.mycompany.whatever.Sustainability`

so make sure you don't miss that one. Also I noticed in the error you pasted that the casing of `ProductionSavingId` is not the same in the hbm you shown. Maybe its a case sensitivity mismatch.